# Web3 CDN error: regeneratorRuntime is not defined

Tags: web3js, web3js-v1.x

When I include the web3 js CDN to my html file, I receive this error

`web3.min.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (web3.min.js:1)`

Here is the CDN I am using

`https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js/dist/web3.min.js`

How do I use this CDN correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your cdn has outdated, i have read the code inside that cdn. It try to call regeneratorRuntime object but they haven’t define that object yet.

You should use the new one instead on this site: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js@1.0.0-beta.34/dist/ (they have fix it)

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/3058 and https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/3155

A workaround is to include polyfill.min.js:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
```

The latest version on cdn is currently:
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/ethereum/web3.js@1.2.1/dist/web3.min.js

Version 1.2.2 is also available via:

```
npm install web3
```